# Jackson annotation unable to parse boolean field

Tags: java, jackson, jackson-databind

My Java class corresponding to the data is as below,

```
package com.some.package;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Builder;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

import java.lang.reflect.Type;


@Data
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class A {
    public static final Type UNMARSHALLER_TYPE = new TypeToken<A>(){}.getType();

    @JsonProperty("id")
    String id;

    @JsonProperty("name")
    String name;

    @JsonProperty("is_enabled")
    boolean isEnabled;
}
```

Test case class which I have written is failing because the isEnabled is always `false`

```
package com.some.package;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import org.junit.Test;

import java.io.IOException;

import static org.junit.Assert.*;

/**
 * Created by tanny on 16/11/19.
 */
public class ATest {

    private static final String RESPONSE_JSON = "{\"is_enabled\": true, \"name\": \"XXX\", \"id\":\"mock-id\", \"num\":12}";

    @Test
    public void testAUnmarshaller() throws IOException {
        // given
        PapiSite payload = new Gson().fromJson(RESPONSE_JSON, A.UNMARSHALLER_TYPE);

        // then
        assertNotNull(payload);
        assertTrue(payload.isEnabled());
        assertEquals("XXX", payload.getName());
    }
}
```

Looks like jackson data binder isn't able to parse the json string passed in the test. Any chance I am doing something wrong?
Any help or guidance would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you are mixing two different libraries `jackson` and `Gson`,  [JsonProperty](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.8/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonProperty.html), [JsonIgnoreProperties](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.6/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonIgnoreProperties.html) belongs to `jackson` and you are trying parse using [Gson](https://static.javadoc.io/com.google.code.gson/gson/2.6.2/com/google/gson/annotations/SerializedName.html) in test case

**Using Gson :** You can use [@SerializedName](https://static.javadoc.io/com.google.code.gson/gson/2.6.2/com/google/gson/annotations/SerializedName.html) while using Gson, you can find more information [here](https://www.baeldung.com/gson-deserialization-guide) about Gson

```
@Data
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class A {
    public static final Type UNMARSHALLER_TYPE = new TypeToken<A>(){}.getType();

   @SerializedName("id")
   String id;

   @SerializedName("name")
   String name;

   @SerializedName("is_enabled")
   boolean isEnabled;
}
```

**Using Jackson :** you can use [ObjectMapper](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.7/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.html), You can find more information [here](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-object-mapper-tutorial) about jackson

```
 @Test
public void testAUnmarshaller() throws IOException {
    // given
   ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    PapiSite payload = objectMapper.readValue(RESPONSE_JSON, A.class); 

    // then
    assertNotNull(payload);
    assertTrue(payload.isEnabled());
    assertEquals("XXX", payload.getName());
}
```

Comment: Actually test case wasn't really my problem. The implemented logic also wasn't able to parse. Now I see even there it has been parsed from gson. Thanks a lot, I need to study more about these.